# PocketBase file size limit

Tags: pocketbase

I am trying to upload images into a collection but the following error pops up when I upload file(s) of size >1MB

`Something went wrong while processing your request.`
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OAlA.png)

The console shows this error for the same

`PATCH ... 413 (Request Entity Too Large)`

The size limit set for the file is greater than 100mb.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KkRu.png)

Can this be resolved?